# In Delphi, what's the keyword for the maximal value for a floating point type?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

**Note: This question has been edited because my issue became something completely different. You'll find the direct answer to the question `What's the keyword for the maximal value for a floating point type?` in [MBo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23358805/540837) - use System.Math's constants.**

Delphi provides multiple floating point value types.
There's Single, Double and Extended to start with.

Last week I looked up what the keyword is for the maximum floating point value and found this: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Infinity

```
var
  float1, float2 : single;
begin
  float1 := Infinity;
  float2 := 23;

  ShowMessage('float1 = '+FloatToStr(float1));
  ShowMessage('float2 = '+FloatToStr(float2));
  ShowMessage('float1 - float2 = '+FloatToStr(float1 - float2));
  ShowMessage('-float1 = '+FloatToStr(-float1));
end;
```

With supposed output

```
float1 = INF
float2 = 23
float1 - float2 = INF
-float1 = -INF
```

I have a form with a component on it. This component has a couple attributes.
If I use the property editor to put `Infinity` as value for the floating point attribute, I get the error that it is an invalid floating point value. Same goes for `INF`.

Then I typed `9.9E308` into the MaxValue field. It transformed into `INF`.

[image: Form Attributes]

Feeling rather pleased about this, I saved my form and went on with my work. I compiled the form later that day, succesfully testing that the form could hold a value of `1E308`.

The next day...

[image: Error on restarting IDE]

Opening the .dfm file in notepad gives me this:

```
object gridDoubleEditor: TdgmrGridDoubleEdit
  Tag = 0
  WantKeyLeftRight = False
  WantKeyUpDown = False
  WantKeyHomeEnd = False
  WantKeyPriorNext = False
  EmptyString = '--'
  EmptyValue = -1E300
  MinValue = -1E300
  MaxValue = INF
  NumberOfDecimals = 2
  Alignment = taRightJustify
  Left = 336
  Top = 208
end
```

**How come it automatically changes `9.9E308` to INF, compiles succesfully, saves succesfully, but fails to load?** Is this a bug in my IDE? I'm using Embarcadero® Delphi® XE5 Version 19.0.14356.6604, 32 bits on Windows 7.

Comment: If a strange error occurs the first thing to do is to close/reopen IDE, reopen the project and rebuild (not just recompile) the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.Math unit contains `Infinity` constant to represent IEEE754 Inf pseudovalue(1.0/0.0). There are also a lot of MaxDouble, MaxExtended etc constants in this unit (look at [Variables section here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Math)). This short test works as needed, so I suspect your component may have some kind of range checking or have property editor that don't understand unknown identificators.

```
  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    FValue: Double;
    procedure SetValue(const Value: Double);
  public
    property Value: Double read FValue write SetValue;
  end;


procedure TForm1.Button26Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TTest.Create(Self) do try
    Value := Infinity;
    Caption := FloatToStr(Value);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

P.S. Do you need to use Infinity as field value, or just to ensure that field value > -1E300?

**P.P.S.**
Why you are still using INF, not Infinity?
BTW, I've found one component with float published property - Object Inspector don't understand Infinity - so  **property editor is not designed for these purposes**, as I've already supposed, but I can assign Infinity in code.

Comment: Is there a way to access these constants so that I can assign them to attributes of a form object? Importing System.Math does allow me to assign Infinity to a floating point variable, but I still can't assign the value to a property of my form object. It says `Infinity is not a valid floating point value` (a similar message appears for all variants - `System.Math.Infinity`, `Math.Infinity`, `MaxSingle`, `Math.MaxSingle`, `System.Math.MaxSingle`...)

Comment: Oh, I've misread your question (looked at INF, didn't noticed Infinity). Could you show 96-97 lines of the code that produces this error.

Comment: Those were just testing lines, with
var f: Double;
begin 
  f := INF;
  f := Infinity;
end
...

Comment: The real issue is that I have a form with a component on it and it used to accept INF for a property. But now all of a sudden it finds such a thing illegal.

Comment: @Pimgd, can you scale down the code to a minimum and provide a compilable example?

Comment: @LU RD I'm afraid I can't because (I think) my problem isn't related to code and more the design mode of RAD Studio. I've updated the question to show how I managed to get INF to display - I'm still wondering how it 'works' now.

I'd prefer it to be -Infinity to Infinity, but it wouldn't accept a thing like -INF so I just put -1E300. An acceptable workaround is just allowing -1E300 to 1E300 as it's big enough, but it still feels silly to me when I know I had it working with INF before.

Comment: RE: P.P.S. When I type 9.9E308 into the MaxValue field, it replaces it with INF. Saving, closing and reopening the file with the component causes the error. I'm using Embarcadero® Delphi® XE5 Version 19.0.14356.6604. I'll try your workaround of setting the attributes at runtime.

Comment: I've updated the question to tell the story in a more logical order. I'll accept your answer because you've solved my problem. Still, I'm left wondering; is this a bug in my IDE? Isn't there a clean way to insert a constant into a property?